# Connect NLog To Database Using Azure KeyVault Connection String In NetCore 3.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, nlog

My nlogconfig file is writing fine to a text file.  It is also writing to a database when I include the connection string in appsettings.json.  Now that we are ready to move to production, I am not going to be housing the connection string in appsettings.json.

However, the problem is that I do not know how to connect mynlogconfig file to a connection string that is located in Azure KeyVault.

How do I take this line of code in nlogconfig

```
connectionString="${configsetting:item=ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection}"
```

and reference the connection string in Azure KeyVault?

My nlogconfig file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
    <add assembly="NLog.Appsettings.Standard"/>
  </extensions>


  <targets>

    <!-- local file target -->
    <target name="fileTarget"
              xsi:type="File"
              fileName="C:\Nlog\logs\meLog.txt"
              layout="
-------------- ${level} (${longdate}) --------------${newline}
${newline}
Call Site: ${callsite}${newline}
Exception Type: ${exception:format=Type}${newline}
Exception Message: ${exception:format=Message}${newline}
Stack Trace: ${exception:format=StackTrace}${newline}
Additional Info: ${message}${newline}" />



    <target xsi:type="Database"
  name="dbTarget"
  connectionString="${configsetting:item=ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection}"
  commandText="INSERT INTO Logs(CreatedOn,Message,Level,Exception,StackTrace,Logger,Url) VALUES (@datetime,@msg,@level,@exception,@trace,@logger,@url)">
      <parameter name="@datetime" layout="${date}" />
      <parameter name="@msg" layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception:format=@}" />
      <parameter name="@trace" layout="${stacktrace}" />
      <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
      <parameter name="@url" layout="${aspnet-request-url}" />
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="dbTarget" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="fileTarget"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

My Program.cs file which is getting the database connection string from Azure KeyVault:

```
using Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using WebApplication6.Models;

namespace WebApplication6
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
         
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
                {
                    string MyClientID = "1MyClientID";
                    string MyTenantID = "1MyTenantID";
                    string MyClientSecretID = "1MyClientSecretID";

                    ClientSecretCredential credential =
                    new ClientSecretCredential(MyTenantID, MyClientID, MyClientSecretID);

                    var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://somerandomurivault.vault.azure.net/"),
                        credential);
                    config.AddAzureKeyVault(secretClient, new KeyVaultSecretManager());
                    config.Build(); 
                })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services)=>
            {
                var databaseConnectionString = hostContext.Configuration.GetValue<string>("databaseConnectionString");
                services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlServer(databaseConnectionString);
                });
            })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

I tried to set the connection string to a global variable, but I had no way of referencing this global variable in the nlogconfig file.

Comment: Maybe NLog GlobalDiagnosticsContext can be used together with [${gdc}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-layout-renderer)

Comment: Can someone please help me?  I have been waiting for two months for some help. :(